# KQL: mv-expand OR bag_unpack equivalent command to convert a list to multiple columns

Tags: azure-log-analytics, azure-data-explorer, kql

According to [mv-expand documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/mvexpandoperator):

> Expands multi-value array or property bag.
>
> mv-expand is applied on a dynamic-typed column so that each value in the collection gets a separate row. All the other columns in an expanded row are duplicated.

Just like the mv-expand operator will create a row each for the elements in the list -- Is there an equivalent operator/way to make each element in a list an additional column?

I checked the documentation and found [Bag_Unpack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/bag-unpackplugin):

> The bag_unpack plugin unpacks a single column of type dynamic by treating each property bag top-level slot as a column.

However, it doesn't seem to work on the list, and rather works on top-level JSON property.

Using bag_unpack (*like the below query*):

```
datatable(d:dynamic)
[
    dynamic({"Name": "John", "Age":20}),
    dynamic({"Name": "Dave", "Age":40}),
    dynamic({"Name": "Smitha", "Age":30}),
]
| evaluate bag_unpack(d)
```

It will do the following:

```
Name    Age
John    20
Dave    40
Smitha  30
```

Is there a command/way (see `some_command_which_helps`) I can achieve the following (*convert a list to columns*):

```
datatable(d:dynamic)
[
    dynamic(["John", "Dave"])
]
| evaluate some_command_which_helps(d)
```

That translates to something like:

```
Col1    Col2
John    Dave
```

Is there an equivalent where I can convert a list/array to multiple columns?

For reference: We can run the above queries online on [Log Analytics](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Monitoring_Logs/DemoLogsBlade) in the demo section if needed (*however, it may require login*).

Answer (score 2):

you could try something along the following lines

*(that said, from an efficiency standpoint, you may want to check your options of restructuring the data set to begin with, using a schema that matches how you plan to actually consume/query it)*

```
datatable(d:dynamic)
[
    dynamic(["John", "Dave"]),
    dynamic(["Janice", "Helen", "Amber"]),
    dynamic(["Jane"]),
    dynamic(["Jake", "Abraham", "Gunther", "Gabriel"]),
]
| extend r = rand()
| mv-expand with_itemindex = i d
| summarize b = make_bag(pack(strcat("Col", i + 1), d)) by r
| project-away r
| evaluate bag_unpack(b)
```

which will output:

```
|Col1  |Col2   |Col3   |Col4   |
|------|-------|-------|-------|
|John  |Dave   |       |       |
|Janice|Helen  |Amber  |       |
|Jane  |       |       |       |
|Jake  |Abraham|Gunther|Gabriel|
```

Answer (score 2):

To extract key value pairs from text and convert them to columns without hardcoding the key names in query:

```
print message="2020-10-15T15:47:09 Metrics: duration=2280, function=WorkerFunction, count=0, operation=copy_into, invocationId=e562f012-a994-4fc9-b585-436f5b2489de, tid=lct_b62e6k59_prd_02, table=SALES_ORDER_SCHEDULE, status=success"
| extend Properties = extract_all(@"(?P<key>\w+)=(?P<value>[^, ]*),?", dynamic(["key","value"]), message)
| mv-apply Properties on (summarize make_bag(pack(tostring(Properties[0]), Properties[1])))
| evaluate bag_unpack(bag_)
| project-away message
```